# Как написать телеграм бота отвечающего на погоду?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, pyowm

пытаюсь создать бота в телеге отвечающего за погоду на питоне. Вот код:

```
import pyowm
from pyowm.owm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config

config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'
owm = OWM('489f45987eb92460dc4955babb3bbeec', config_dict)

import telebot

owm = pyowm.OWM('489f45987eb92460dc4955babb3bbeec')
mgr =  owm.weather_manager()

bot = telebot.TeleBot("1317148098:AAFoaJ5MVh-Q6Y2c2fCpRL496CbivpersAg")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_echo(message):
    observation =  mgr.weather_at_place( message.text )
    w =  observation.weather
    temp = w.temperature('celsius')["temp"]

    answer = "В городе " + message.text + " сейчас " + w.detailed_status() + "\n"
    answer += " Температура сейчас в районе "+ str(temp) + "\n\n"

    if temp < 10:
        answer += "Сейчас жестко холодно, кырык кабат киын" 
    elif temp < 20:
        answer += "Сейчас холодно, оденься потеплее" 
    else:
        answer += "Температура найс, одевайся как хош" 

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)
bot.polling( none_stop = True)
```

Делаю почти также как в этом видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fp5-XQFr_nk&t=3427s (чуть по другому потому что если делать как у него работать вообще не будет)

на что выходит такая ошибка:

```
 2020-09-24 03:04:43,544 (util.py:75 WorkerThread1) ERROR - TeleBot: "TypeError occurred, args=("'str' object is not callable",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\byrym\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 69, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\byrym\Desktop\ЕРХАТ\программирование\python\second.py", line 22, in send_echo
    answer = "В городе " + message.text + " сейчас " + w.detailed_status() + "\n"
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\byrym\Desktop\ЕРХАТ\программирование\python\second.py", line 33, in <module>
    bot.polling( none_stop = True)
  File "C:\Users\byrym\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 427, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\byrym\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 451, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\byrym\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 118, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "C:\Users\byrym\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\byrym\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 69, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\byrym\Desktop\ЕРХАТ\программирование\python\second.py", line 22, in send_echo
    answer = "В городе " + message.text + " сейчас " + w.detailed_status() + "\n"
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Я чувствую что это исправить легко, но уже 2 часа не мог найти ответа. (только начинаю обучение питона)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка такого вида означает, что у объект (а именно у строки) вызывали как функцию, т.е. использовали круглые скобки.

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Строки нет смысла вызывать как функции.

Попробуйте (добавил еще форматирование строки):

```
answer = f"В городе {message.text} сейчас {w.detailed_status}\n"
```